# Enabling SE_DEBUG_NAME in c#

Tags: c#, process, privileges, elevated-privileges

I am currently developing a C# application that is used to monitor few other processes. I want to take the dumps of these processes occasionally. For this, currently I am PInvoking `MiniDumpWriteDump()` function. I have both a command line utility and a graphical utility, which PInvokes the `MiniDumpWriteDump()` function. The problem I am currently facing is that I get perfect memory dumps when using the command line utility, but from the graphical utility that calls the same function, it creates an empty file every time( even when run as administrator ).
The `GetLastWin32Error()` gives `0x80000057` - `Parameter is invalid`, but I am passing exactly the same values to my PInvoked function in both cases. So I am suspecting the invalid value error is from some call the `MiniDumpWriteDump()` is making internally and my best guess is that this is a process privilege issue. I would like to know a few things here :

1. Is there any difference in privileges between a command line utility and a graphical utility by default on launch?
2. If its not a privilege issue, what can be the possible causes of the problem I am faced with?
3. If it is a problem with privileges, is there any way of enabling `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege from my utility using C# ( without PInvoking `AdjustTokenPrivileges()` and associated functions ) ?

Here is My PInvoke declaration :

```
public enum Typ : uint
    {
        // From dbghelp.h:
        MiniDumpNormal = 0x00000000,
        MiniDumpWithDataSegs = 0x00000001,
        MiniDumpWithFullMemory = 0x00000002,
        MiniDumpWithHandleData = 0x00000004,
        MiniDumpFilterMemory = 0x00000008,
        MiniDumpScanMemory = 0x00000010,
        MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules = 0x00000020,
        MiniDumpWithIndirectlyReferencedMemory = 0x00000040,
        MiniDumpFilterModulePaths = 0x00000080,
        MiniDumpWithProcessThreadData = 0x00000100,
        MiniDumpWithPrivateReadWriteMemory = 0x00000200,
        MiniDumpWithoutOptionalData = 0x00000400,
        MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo = 0x00000800,
        MiniDumpWithThreadInfo = 0x00001000,
        MiniDumpWithCodeSegs = 0x00002000,
        MiniDumpWithoutAuxiliaryState = 0x00004000,
        MiniDumpWithFullAuxiliaryState = 0x00008000,
        MiniDumpWithPrivateWriteCopyMemory = 0x00010000,
        MiniDumpIgnoreInaccessibleMemory = 0x00020000,
        MiniDumpWithTokenInformation = 0x00040000,
        MiniDumpValidTypeFlags = 0x0003ffff,
    };

[DllImport("dbghelp.dll",
      EntryPoint = "MiniDumpWriteDump",
      CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
      CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
      ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool MiniDumpWriteDump(
      IntPtr hProcess,
      uint processId,
      IntPtr hFile,
      uint dumpType,
      IntPtr expParam,
      IntPtr userStreamParam,
      IntPtr callbackParam);

    public static bool Write(string fileName, IntPtr prochandle, uint procid)
    {
        return Write(fileName, (Typ.MiniDumpWithFullMemory|Typ.MiniDumpWithDataSegs|Typ.MiniDumpWithHandleData|Typ.MiniDumpWithThreadInfo|Typ.MiniDumpWithTokenInformation), prochandle, procid);
    }

    public static bool Write(string fileName, Typ dumpTyp, IntPtr prochandle, uint procid)
    {
        using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.None))
        {
            bool bRet = MiniDumpWriteDump(
              prochandle,
              procid,
              fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
              (uint)dumpTyp,
              IntPtr.Zero,
              IntPtr.Zero,
              IntPtr.Zero);
            if (!bRet)
            {
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
            return bRet;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I call it (using the same function dump() from both console and GUI application):

```
void dump(procId, filePath)
{
  Process p = Process.GetProcessById(procId);
  MiniDumper.Write(filePath, p.Handle, (uint)p.Id);
}
```

Comment: This is unlikely, more likely that you got the pinvoke declaration wrong.  Some mistake that makes it work in 32-bit mode but not in 64-bit mode.  Of course we can't see it, posting a repro snippet for misbehaving code is a requirement here.

Comment: @HansPassant I might have got the declaration wrong, I am relatively new to PInvoke. Anyway I am posting the code snippet.

Comment: Hans is probably right, but what's wrong with using `AdjustTokenPrivileges`? It's not fun, but the correct P/Invoke signatures are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510311/how-can-i-manipulate-token-privileges-in-net

Comment: @Gabe Just a little hesitation to play with another PInvoke. But if there is no other option, I will go for it anyways. Thanks a lot for the signatures btw.

Comment: Keep in mind that the debug privilege is only necessary for debugging other users' processes. If you can't do a minidump on your own [non-elevated] process, the problem isn't that you need a privilege.

Comment: @Gabe With a bit more of tests and stuff, now even I think Hans is right. But I can't figure out what is going wrong. If it is a problem with 32/64 bit modes, and if i run the console application using C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe, will it make any difference?

Comment: It's your build settings that determine bitness (x86, x64), not which command prompt you use.

Comment: @Gabe No I was just asking whether the Windows 32-bit on Windows 64 subsystem can have any effect on the execution. I am building it for Any CPU.